# passing input from text file as arguments for aws route53

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm having trouble passing in parameters from my text file to aws route53.

```
for line in $(cat input.txt);
do aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $line;
done
```

returns an error saying

```
No hosted zone found with ID: myid"
```

but manually calling the following

```
do aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id myid
```

returns desired result. This issue seems fairly trivial, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: is that doublequote actually in the input.txt?

Comment: Remove the call to 'aws route53' for the moment. Just parse the input.txt file in your loop and print $line each time. Does it have the values you expect (and that are appropriate for the aws route53 command)?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your usage, the problem lies in your input.txt file.

For testing i have this in my txt file:

`$ cat input.txt
a foo
b
c
d`

and to verify it:

`$ for line in $(cat input.txt); do echo aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $line; done
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id a
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id foo
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id b
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id c
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id d`

Note that the for interprets both spaces and newlines (because of cat), so "a foo" will show as two iterations unless you properly modify your for loop to properly iterate over only lines in the file (and properly add single quotes to avoid passing multiple arguments where one was expected to `--hosted-zone-id`

`$ while read line; do echo aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id "'${line}'"; done <input.txt
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id 'a foo'
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id 'b'
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id 'c'
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id 'd'`